# Как узнать, что под капотом у CLR функции

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, clr, sqlclr

На сервере, который я обслуживаю, имеется много CLR объектов. Я впервые сталкиваюсь с ними. Возможно, они работают неправильно, и нужна оптимизация. Исходников нет. Как-то можно узнать код данных объектов? Вероятно, они написаны на c#. Пробовал запустить профайлер, но кроме как "EXEC 'Name Of Clr object'" там не увидел. Как я понимаю, речь идёт о дизассемблировании DLL файла?

Comment: Можно через ilspy посмотреть, например, что там внутри

Comment: @Александр, спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: Можете еще посмотреть ildasm.exe (он встроен в сам .net framework) и dotPeek (от jetbrains). Некоторые инструменты предоставляют только IL код, некоторые могут попробовать привести аналогичный C# код.

Comment: @AlexKrass, да уж, привести всё к C# - это было бы вообще космос)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функции SQLCLR могут быть представлены либо одной скомпилированной DLL, либо DLL с исходниками, если ее залили таким образом (что стандартный шаблон проекта и делает, насколько я знаю). Перечень функций можно получить запросом

```
select * from sys.assembly_modules
```

Который вернет что-то такое:

```
object_id   assembly_id     assembly_class          assembly_method ...
1573580644  65551           UserDefinedFunctions    Func1           ...
1589580701  65551           UserDefinedFunctions    Func2           ...
```

**assembly_id** указывает на сборку, в которой лежит код функции. Сборки можно получить запросом к системной таблице [sys.assemblies](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-assemblies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Файлы, соответствующие сборкам, хранятся в [sys.assembly_files](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-assembly-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Извлечь С# код из скомпилированной сборки можно с помощью библиотеки [ICSharpCode.Decompiler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ICSharpCode.Decompiler).

Пример запроса для вывода списка файлов:

```sql
SELECT assemblies.name, 
 assemblies.assembly_id, 
 assembly_files.name as "filename"
FROM sys.assemblies
INNER JOIN sys.assembly_files  ON assemblies.assembly_id = assembly_files.assembly_id
```

Пример вывода кода всех файлов указанной сборки на C#:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using ICSharpCode.Decompiler;
using ICSharpCode.Decompiler.CSharp;

class SqlClrAssFile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

    public static IEnumerable<SqlClrAssFile> GetAssemblyFiles(string assname)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder build = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        build.DataSource = "SERVER";
        build.InitialCatalog = "mydb";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(build.ConnectionString);
        List<SqlClrAssFile> files = new List<SqlClrAssFile>();

        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                "SELECT assembly_files.name as filename,content FROM sys.assemblies "+
                " INNER JOIN sys.assembly_files ON assemblies.assembly_id = assembly_files.assembly_id " +
                " WHERE assemblies.name=@name", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", assname);
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            using (rd)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (rd.Read() == false) break;
                    SqlClrAssFile file = new SqlClrAssFile();
                    file.Name = (string)rd["filename"];
                    file.Data = (byte[])rd["content"];
                    files.Add(file);
                }

                return files;
            }
        }        
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<SqlClrAssFile> files = GetAssemblyFiles("MyClrAssembly");

        foreach (var x in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*****"+x.Name+ "*****");
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(x.Name);

            if (ext == ".cs")
            {
                //показать файл исходников
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x.Data));
            }
            else if (ext == ".dll" || ext == "")
            {
                try
                {
                    //показать декомпилированную DLL
                    string name = Path.GetFileName(x.Name);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(name, x.Data);
                    CSharpDecompiler decompiler = new CSharpDecompiler(name, new DecompilerSettings());

                    Console.WriteLine("[Decompiled]");
                    Console.WriteLine(decompiler.DecompileWholeModuleAsString());                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[Unknown file: {0} bytes]",x.Data.Length);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Здесь мы просто преобразуем байты в текст для .cs файлов, а для DLL выгружаем в файл и декомпилируем.